# Как программно в Аndroid'e вызвать удаление своего приложения?

Tags: android

Я подозреваю, что удаление производится каким-то методом, который на вход принимает имя пакета (во всяком случае я считаю это разумным), но нигде не могу найти такую информацию. Подскажите?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то такое?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.android.myapp"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Возможно,сейчас проверю

Comment: Наверное, только с рутом так можно. Как вариант - можно ломать функционал, чтобы запускалось с ошибкой всегда.

Comment: @Deadkenny да, для этого рут нужен. Иначу дыра в безопасности бы была.

Comment: Допустим, что такой вариант не подходит. Но я считаю, что разработчик имеет право на удаление без подтверждения своего приложения, если оно не прошло лицензию. Думаю, что способ такой есть.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK разработчик даже должен место своего проживания (или регистрации предприятия) писать на странице приложения. По правилам гугла у разработчика немного прав. Хотя сам гугл себе выделил право удалённо удалять любое приложение, установленное из маркета...

Comment: > разработчик даже должен место своего проживания (или регистрации предприятия) писать на странице приложения

Ничего подобного, не выдумывайте.

Comment: @falstaf вы почитайте последнее обновление. Теперь надо свой почтовый адрес писать. Иначе могут забанить.

Comment: @Suvitruf, читал и перечитал ещё раз. Не могли бы вы конкретно указать пункт в соглашении, который говорит, что "разработчик должен указывать свой почтовый адрес"?

Comment: @falstaf оповещения в админке смотрите. http://habrahabr.ru/post/238611/